# Unable to fetch file from google drive

Tags: java, android, file-upload, google-drive-android-api

I am working on a project where user can upload a document to my server. This file can be selected either from local storage or a cloud storage ,say google drive. When i click on the file from file chooser all i am receiving is an account info and doc info as a uri, When i tried to fetch doc from this URI it is showing FileNotFound . I have gone through Drive API also but It is a bit confusing to me. Following are the points i came accross while trying Google Drive API:
1. How to select file from local storage.
2. How do I get FileId form the selected file.

I tried with the following code snippet:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.setType("**/");

    startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
```

and In onActivityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                             Intent resultData) {

    // The ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent was sent with the request code
    // READ_REQUEST_CODE. If the request code seen here doesn't match, it's the
    // response to some other intent, and the code below shouldn't run at all.

    if (requestCode == 1000 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // The document selected by the user won't be returned in the intent.
        // Instead, a URI to that document will be contained in the return intent
        // provided to this method as a parameter.
        // Pull that URI using resultData.getData().
        Uri uri = null;
        if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();
            Log.i("URI", "Uri: " + uri.toString());
            try {
                readTextFromUri(uri);
                getMimeType(this,uri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //     showImage(uri);
        }
    }
}
 private String readTextFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
  //  FileInputStream fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(uri.)
    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            inputStream));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
    }

  //  fileInputStream.close();
  //  parcelFileDescriptor.close();
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Conclusion:

Can anyone please send me a link how to upload a document(I should even check the extension of the document) from both local storage and Google drive in a File chooser.

Comment: Better add a comment while voting down.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.example.ayyappaboddupalli.gdrive;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentSender;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
    import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
    import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveContents;
    import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFile;
    import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId;
    import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveResourceClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.drive.OpenFileActivityOptions;
    import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.Filters;
    import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.SearchableField;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource;
    import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private static final String TAG = "Google drive";
    private static final String SIGN_IN = "Sign In";
    private static final String DOWNLOAD_FILE = "Download file";

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_ITEM = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE = 112;


    private GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount;
    private Set<Scope> requiredScopes;
    private DriveClient mDriveClient;
    private DriveResourceClient mDriveResourceClient;

    private OpenFileActivityOptions openOptions;
    private TaskCompletionSource<DriveId> mOpenItemTaskSource;
    private java.io.File storageDir;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView( R.layout.activity_main);

        initialize();
        requestPermission();
        signInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);

        if (signInAccount != null && signInAccount.getGrantedScopes().containsAll(requiredScopes)) {
            initializeDriveClient(signInAccount);
        } else {
           // onDriveClientReady();
            signIn();


        }
        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Submit);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onDriveClientReady();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Task<GoogleSignInAccount> getAccountTask = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
                    if (getAccountTask.isSuccessful()) {
                        initializeDriveClient(getAccountTask.getResult());
                        showMessage("Sign in successfully.");
//                        binding.btnSubmit.setText(DOWNLOAD_FILE);
                    } else {
                        showMessage("Sign in failed.");
                    }
                } else {
                    showMessage("Sign in failed.");
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_ITEM:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    DriveId driveId = data.getParcelableExtra(OpenFileActivityOptions.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
                    mOpenItemTaskSource.setResult(driveId);
                } else {
                    mOpenItemTaskSource.setException(new RuntimeException("Unable to open file"));
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    private void initialize() {

        requiredScopes = new HashSet<>(2);
        requiredScopes.add(Drive.SCOPE_FILE);
        requiredScopes.add(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER);

        openOptions = new OpenFileActivityOptions.Builder()
                .setSelectionFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "application/pdf"))
                .setActivityTitle("Select file")
                .build();
    }

    private void initializeDriveClient(GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) {
        mDriveClient = Drive.getDriveClient(getApplicationContext(), signInAccount);
        mDriveResourceClient = Drive.getDriveResourceClient(getApplicationContext(), signInAccount);
    }


    private void signIn() {
        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                .build();
        GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
        startActivityForResult(googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);
    }

    private void onDriveClientReady() {
        mOpenItemTaskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<>();
        mDriveClient.newOpenFileActivityIntentSender(openOptions)
                .continueWith(new Continuation<IntentSender, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void then(@NonNull Task<IntentSender> task) throws Exception {
                        startIntentSenderForResult(
                                task.getResult(), REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_ITEM, null, 0, 0, 0);
                        return null;
                    }
                });

        Task<DriveId> tasks = mOpenItemTaskSource.getTask();
        tasks.addOnSuccessListener(this,
                new OnSuccessListener<DriveId>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DriveId driveId) {
                        retrieveContents(driveId.asDriveFile());
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        showMessage("File not selected.");
                    }
                });
    }

    private void retrieveContents(final DriveFile file) {
        // [START open_file]
        final Task<DriveContents> openFileTask = mDriveResourceClient.openFile(file, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY);
        // [END open_file]
        // [START read_contents]
        openFileTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<DriveContents, Task<Void>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Void> then(@NonNull Task<DriveContents> task) throws Exception {
                DriveContents contents = task.getResult();

                Log.v(TAG, "File name : " + contents.toString());
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    InputStream input = contents.getInputStream();

                    try {
                        java.io.File file = new java.io.File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "umesh.pdf");
                        Log.v(TAG, storageDir + "");
                        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        try {
                            try {
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
                                int read;

                                while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                                }
                                output.flush();
                            } finally {
                                output.close();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            input.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                showMessage("Download file successfully.");
                return mDriveResourceClient.discardContents(contents);
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        showMessage("Unable to download file.");
                    }
                });
        // [END read_contents]
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        String dirPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + java.io.File.separator + "PDF";
        storageDir = new java.io.File(dirPath);
        if (!storageDir.exists())
            storageDir.mkdirs();}}
```

//in gradle

```
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev110-1.23.0'
```